# Why i can't add data/image to my database but it says success

Tags: php, mysql, database

Why i can't add data/image to my database but it says success

I need some help my table name is `prods` columns are

```
    Product_ID is AI
    prodPic 
    prodName   
    prodPrice 
    Type 
    prodQuant
```

```
    <?php
        include('connect.php');
    ?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="gallery">
            <?php
    
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM prods ORDER BY Type DESC";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                echo "SQL statement failed!";
            }else {
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo '<a href="#">
                <div style="background-image: url(img/'.$row["prodPic"].') ;"></div>
                <h3>'.$row["prodName"].'</h3>
                <p>'.$row["prodPrice"].'</p>
            </a>';
                }
            }
            echo '<a href="#">
                <div></div>
                <h3></h3>
                <p></p>
            </a>'
            ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form action="up.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="File name">
                <input type="text" name="fileTitle" placeholder="Image Name">
                <input type="text" name="fileDesc" placeholder="Price">
                <input type="file" name="file">
                <button type="submit" name="submit"> Upload </button>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
    <?php
    include('connect.php');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $newfileName = $_POST['filename'];
        if(empty($newfileName)){
            $newfileName = uniqid('', true);
        }else{
            $newfileName = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $newfileName));
        }
        $imgName = $_POST['fileTitle'];
        $imgPrice = $_POST['fileDesc'];
        $file = $_FILES['file'];
        $fileName = $file["name"];
        $fileTempName = $file["tmp_name"];
        $fileExt = explode(".", $fileName);
        $fileAExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

        $allowed = array("jpg" , "jpeg" , "png");
    
        if (in_array($fileAExt, $allowed)) {
            $imgFName = $newfileName . "." . uniqid("", false) . "." . $fileAExt;
            $fileDest = "img/" . $imgFName;
            if (empty($imgName) || empty($imgPrice)) {
                header("location: up.php?upload=failed");
                exit();
            }else{
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM prods;";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
                if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
                    echo "sql statement error";
                }else{
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                    $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    $simgOrder = $rowCount + 1;
    
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO prods 
                                    (prodPic, prodName, prodPrice, Type) 
                            VALUES (?,?,?,?);";
                    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
                        echo "sql statement error";
                    }else{
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $imgFName,$imgName, $imgPrice, $simgOrder );
                        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                        move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $fileDest);
                        header("location: up.php?upload=success");
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo "Invalid File Type";
            exit();
        }
    }  
    ?>
```

Comment: There is a reason for the mesage that tells you there is not enough text in your question and the solution is NOT to add the little bit of text multiple times

Comment: There is no point/benefit/reason to PREPARE a query that contains NO parameters

Comment: @RiggsFolly. can you help me? i'm still a newbie to this i just keep looking for online tutorial but still i don't get it. i debugged it for almost a day still i don't get why it would not save store data to my database.

Comment: If you want to know how many rows there are in a table, do a `SELECT COUNT(id) ...`Not a `select *` there could be a million rows in that table and you will waste time getting your DBMS to actually select all that data, for you to just ignore it

Comment: Does this code save the file to you `img` folder?

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: yes it saves the file to img folder but not in the database

Comment: @RiggsFolly No need, but also no harm, and if they learn the habit of always using prepared statements it's better.

Comment: Did the error reportng code identify your issue?